# Google Analytics filter to combine /home.aspx and /

Tags: filter, google-analytics

the following urls are the same page, I'd like it to be recognized as the same page in Google Analytics. What filter do I create so it's not replicated?

/contact/home.aspx
& 
/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search and replace filter should do that for you:

1. create a new filter > search and replace
2. select the filter field `Request URI`
3. in the search string field `/contact/home\.aspx`
4. in the replace string field add `/contact/`

Screenshot:

[image]